# iTerm2 style fullscreen on OSX

Tags: osx, frames

iTerm2 has the ability to use "old-school" (non-Lion) style fullscreen. Emacs can do this too: `(setq ns-use-native-fullscreen nil)`. iTerm2, however, allows you to keep the native OSX menu bar (the one that's glued to the top of the screen) visible while in this fullscreen mode. To be as explicit as possible, this configuration differs from a simply maximized iTerm2 because the title bar of the window (the one with the red, yellow, and green buttons) is not there.

Can this setup be replicated in Emacs? I'm using the homebrew version of Emacs, but open to other solutions.

Comment: I believe the answer is "no", sorry.  There are lots of other alternatives, but not one that fits precisely with the call of the question.

Comment: There used to be patch from a Japanese user that allowed for this, but only worked on older versions of Emacs. Emacs sources had to be compiled with this patch and with a specific version of Xcode. It stopped working as newer versions of Emacs and Xcode were released.